# Check if list element is within another list - Elixir

Tags: elixir

If I have two lists:

First list => `[1,2,3]`
Second List => `[3,4,5]`

I want this to return true because they both contain `3`? If `3` was replaced by `6` it would return false because no elements would match.

Current Attempt

```
Enum.member?(first_list, fn(x) -> x == second_list end)
```

Ecto queries:

```
user_teams = from(
  t in MyApp.Team,
  left_join: a in assoc(t, :accounts),
  where: p.owner_id == ^user.id or (a.user_id == ^user.id and t.id == a.project_id)
) |> Repo.all

current_user_teams = from(
  t in MyApp.Team,
  left_join: a in assoc(t, :accounts),
  where: t.owner_id == ^current_user.id or (a.user_id == ^current_user.id and p.id == a.project_id)
) |> Repo.all
```

Current Fix:

```
Enum.any?(user_projects, fn(p) -> p in current_user_projects end)
```

Comment: I hope that your two lists aren't result of Ecto queries, otherwise there are more performant ways to solve this.

Comment: They are! I'm curious what the ways are? Can you point me to a resource? Thank You!

Comment: you need to provide us example code with queries and we will be able to provide you answer, as it is hard to tell from what you have written there.

Comment: @Hauleth Updated.

Comment: you should create new question with your new problem. But other than that see that what you need is simple `and` within query.

Comment: Interesting, I'll make a new question and send you the link. Thanks for the help.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51499940/make-ecto-queries-more-efficient @Hauleth

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Use `Enum.any?/2` with the `in` operator (which is just a shorter form of calling `Enum.member?/2`):

```
iex(1)> xs = [1, 2, 3]
[1, 2, 3]
iex(2)> ys = [3, 4, 5]
[3, 4, 5]
iex(3)> Enum.any?(xs, fn x -> x in ys end)
true
```

Comment: However it will have complexity `O(n * m)`. If you have large lists then you can use `not MapSet.disjoint?(MapSet.new(xs), MapSet.new(ys))`.

Comment: @Hauleth Agreed, your solution is `O(max(n, m) log max(n, m))`. I'd guess it'll be faster only when `n * m` is > 10k-100k.

Comment: @Hauleth, Can also just use one MapSet.  `ys_mapset=MapSet.new(ys)` `Enum.any?(xs, fn x -> x in ys_mapset end) `

Answer (score 7):

If lists are large then you can use `MapSet` to check if these lists are disjoint:

```
iex(1)> xs = [1, 2, 3]
[1, 2, 3]
iex(2)> ys = [3, 4, 5]
[3, 4, 5]
iex(3)> not MapSet.disjoint?(MapSet.new(xs), MapSet.new(ys))
true
```

And if you want to know what is the intersection (elements that are common in both sets) then you can use:

```
iex(1)> xs = [1, 2, 3]
[1, 2, 3]
iex(2)> ys = [3, 4, 5]
[3, 4, 5]
iex(3)> MapSet.intersect(MapSet.new(xs), MapSet.new(ys))
#MapSet<[3]>
```

Answer (score 2):

You might get in intersection in the first place, and then validate whether it’s empty or not:

```
case for i <- [1,2,3], i in [3,4,5], do: i do
  [] -> false
  [_|_] -> true
end
```