# Make Ecto queries more efficient

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework, ecto

I'm trying to see if my current user's teams overlap with the passed in user's teams. I have something that works but I'm curious if it could me more efficient. Here is what I have:

```
user_teams = from(
  t in MyApp.Team,
  left_join: a in assoc(t, :accounts),
  where: p.owner_id == ^user.id or (a.user_id == ^user.id and t.id == a.project_id)
) |> Repo.all

current_user_teams = from(
  t in MyApp.Team,
  left_join: a in assoc(t, :accounts),
  where: t.owner_id == ^current_user.id or (a.user_id == ^current_user.id and p.id == a.project_id)
) |> Repo.all
```

And then I compare them with:

```
Enum.any?(user_teams, fn(t) -> t in current_user_teams end)
```

Again, this suits my needs but seems like there is probably a better way to do this?

Comment: Do you use either `user_teams` or `current_user_teams` later in this request? If so, I guess you need to keep it how it is, but if not you could just do a single query that only gets teams if both the given user and the current user are part of the team.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest solution would be just to join these two queries into one and check if resulting query returns anything. So let's do exactly that:

```
query = from t in MyApp.Team,
  left_join: a in assoc(t, :accounts),
  where: p.owner_id == ^user.id or (a.user_id == ^user.id and t.id == a.project_id),
  where: t.owner_id == ^current_user.id or (a.user_id == ^current_user.id and p.id == a.project_id),
  limit: 1,
  select: true

not is_nil(Repo.one(query))
```

This will simulate `SELECT EXIST (…)` query from PostgreSQL (in Ecto 3.0 there will be `Repo.exist?/1` function that will do exactly that, [related issue](https://github.com/elixir-ecto/ecto/issues/2454)).

Duplicated `where` fragments will be `AND`ed by default.